# What is the difference between sqlx.Connect() and sqlx.Open()?

Tags: go, sqlx

I am using [jmoiron sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) library for my golang project. I tried to create a db connection mysql. So, I found these two functions: `sqlx.Connect()` and `sqlx.Open()`, but didn't found the difference.

So, I tried to read the documentation in [godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx). I found this:

**sqlx.Connect()**

```
Connect to a database and verify with a ping.
```

**sqlx.Open()**

```
Open is the same as sql.Open, but returns an *sqlx.DB instead.
```

I know that `sqlx.Open()` create a connection to the database using golang `sql.Open`. But what is `sqlx.Connect()` use?

If I see inside the source code here:

```
func Connect(driverName, dataSourceName string) (*DB, error) {
    db, err := Open(driverName, dataSourceName)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        db.Close()
        return nil, err
    }
    return db, nil
}
```

I can see that it called the same `sqlx.Open()` then calling `db.Ping()`. So the the only difference is that `sqlx.Open()` execute ping after create connection? If so, why it does ping? What makes it different?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Connect will use open and ping to check for the valid connection which you can then handle the error.

Basically you can see right away that the db connection isn't there in one method rather than writing that code yourself again.